# Following code is not reaching the else statement

Tags: php, if-statement, operators

Disclaimer: I'm new to programming, this is a simple exercise I'm doing so go easy on me.

The following code is not reaching (printing) the else statement. Any insight is much appreciated.

```
$number = '1120011';

    // Decimal check
    if($number[0] == '+' && $number[1] == '0'){
        echo "Error: Can't assign a plus sign on a leading zero!";
    // Leading zero check    
    } elseif($number[0] == '+' || $number[0] == '-'){
        echo "Number is decimal";
    // Binary check    
    } elseif (preg_match('~^[01]+$~', $number)) {
        echo "Number is binary";
    // Code not executing here. For e.g. $number = 1120011    
    } else {
        "Number is non binary";
    }
```

Another question:

Why is the following 'if' not working properly (if I replace it in the code above). I guess it has something to do with bad usage of operators.

```
if($number[0] == '+' || $number[0] == '-' && $number[1] == '0')
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You have to be careful with || and &&, try putting in brackets round the || terms.

Comment: That just solved it :) Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Wait but I'm really confused. I put your code into a local php file, executed it, and *NOTHING* echos. Logically, something should echo. The `else` based on the logic. I do not understand. What was the exact solution?

Comment: The second question was solved. The brackets around the || terms did the job.
However I am still struggling with the original (first) question.

Comment: Big facepalm! There is no echo in the else statement :D

Answer (score 0):

For the second question:

```
if($number[0] == '+' || $number[0] == '-' && $number[1] == '0')
```

try

```
if(($number[0] == '+')||(($number[0] == '-')&&($number[1] == '0')))
```